# High latency when reading frame from webcam with python opencv on Raspberry

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi running OpenCV in python. When I read a frame from a webcam I get a frame that is 5-10 seconds old. I tested this using the following code and pointing the webcam at the screen:

```
for i in range(50):
    print(time.time())
    time.sleep(0.01)
print("")
r, frame = cam.read()
```

When I read 10 frames in a row, the last one is new:

```
for i in range(50):
    print(time.time())
    time.sleep(0.01)
print("")
for i in range(10):
    print(time.time())
    r, frame = cam.read()
```

How do I achieve that I don't have to read multiple frames but get a fresh one the first time?

The webcam is a Logitech C270.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `print()` in the second loop?

Comment: Right now I'm unable to get the code working again... When I succeed, I'll post the output.

Comment: I got it working once again, though there's nothing interesting about the output, it prints the current time 50 times then does the same 10 times but takes a picture. In the end the frame captured shows the terminal with all the timestamps printed previously.

Comment: And that is not what you expected? You're overwriting to the variable `frame`, you'll always be left with the last captured image. Your question doesn't seem to go with the code you posted.

Comment: That's exactly what I was expecting. What I wasn't expecting though is that the _first_ code returns a frame that was captured about 5-10 seconds ago and that's my problem.

Comment: Well, that just can't be explained..

Comment: I also observed certain latency (though less than the 5-10 seconds) using the exact same setup. Mine shows after about 2-2.5 seconds. Try using another webcam- just to know if it's caused due to webcam or pi.